# a vertex is not inside of gizumo's circle

Tags: interface

i get annoyed for this. 
Is this proper behavior or a bug?
Can i fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is intended functionality. You are using a subdivision modifier and viewing the geometry generated by it while controlling the actual geometry. Since the modifier smooths the surface, the locations of the vertices change.

You can toggle the preview of the effects of the modifier in the Properties Editor, Modifier Properties tab:

[image]